# No cordova.local.properties file after wrapping Sencha Touch with Cordova

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

Why don’t I get the cordova.local.properties file? I did execute the steps exactly as explained in Sencha Docs with no errors.It just stopped building, giving the output below. 
I use Sencha Touch 2.3.1a, Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231 and Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6.
What am i missing here?

```
[xxx@xxx:/Projects/SenchaTouch2/TestApp]$ sencha cordova init org.example.app

Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[INF] Creating App
[INF] App.json already contains a builds object. Please configure build / packager definitions in app.json manually.
[INF] Application has been initialized for native packaging. Please edit app.json and add platform(s) to build for.

[xxx@xxx:/Projects/SenchaTouch2/TestApp]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution. In this version, the cordova.local.properties is not generated!
So I editted in app.json this line to :

```
"platforms": "ios android",
```

and added the js:

```
    {
        "path": "cordova.js",
        "remote": true
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

Apparently, you have to really just follow what the exception tells you to do: edit the app.json manually. There is this piece of code there that you just have to uncomment, and then you're good to go.
So just uncomment

```
"platform": "ios"
```

and go build it.

PS: my first answer on stackOverflow!

Comment: I actually editted in app.jspn this line to :
    "platforms": "ios android",
and added the js: 
      {
   "path": "cordova.js",
   "remote": true
  },